# report viewer control exporting content to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

I am creating asp.net net app for a client and he likes to have reports on his page so i have on the page rdlc file and im using default asp.net report viewer control to present this file on the page...everything is ok except when the client wants to save the file as pdf the structure of the page changes and it doesnt look the same also i have notice that some of the values in fields are empty but they appear on the page and when im saving the same report in Word(*.doc) format also the word file is like it should be...the problem is only with the pdf. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was due to the Margins settings in the Report Properties if you are having the same problem set the Margins settings (Left,Right,Top,Bottom) to 0in. And your problem is solve.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was missing. I was on the ReportViewer control instead of the actual .rdlc report properties. Thank you!

Comment: tanks a lot 
after 4 years from answer it really really helped me
tanks again

Comment: please  i don't find the margins settings when i see the report properties . can u explain please

Comment: @BennaniHAMZA try selecting the document and then F4 i remember there where to two sets of properties one by right clicking on the document and the other one by pressing F4 if i remember correctly... but im off from this stuff years ago so sorry if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code.... it will help to displayy u r data in pdf format

```
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindReportData();  
        try
        {
            // Export the Report to Response stream in PDF format and file name Customers

            abc_reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "ABC");
            // There are other format options available such as Word, Excel, CVS, and HTML in the ExportFormatType Enum given by crystal reports
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            ex = null;
        }
    }



    private void bindReportData()
    {
        abc_reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        dsReport = new DataSet();
        dsReport = getAccumulationData();
        if (dsReport.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            abc_reportDocument.Load(this.MapPath("report1.rpt"));
            abc_reportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dsReport.Tables[0]);
            rptviewerAccumulation.ReportSource = abc_reportDocument;
            rptviewerAccumulation.DataBind();


        }

}
```

Comment: Thx but im not using Crystal reports, only SQL server reports client side...RDLC file in the web app and default report viewer control for displaying this file

Comment: ok...  no problem...  but not somuch difference while doing this

Comment: hey Flip .... U go through link

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/519/posts/12873/sql-server-develop-reports-with-rdlc-aspnet.aspx

Comment: Yes @Niks thats the way i go to build the report but when exporting it in pdf the first page is ok in the pdf file and from the second to the end all the fields (position and size ) differs from the original the way they look in the page